# C# Find object inside List object

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do Is, find an object inside a list

```
Log q = logs.Find(x => (x.dnsq.queryID.Contains(queryid)));
```

However when I do it, I get this error

> x.dnsq.queryID = 'x.dnsq.queryID' threw an exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException

The Log class looks like this

```
class Log : LogCtrl
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public string source { set; get; }
    public string destination { set; get; }
    public string protocol { set; get; }
    public double time { set; get; }
    public string info { set; get; }
    public DNSresponse dnsr { set; get; }
    public DNSquery dnsq { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: one of your object is null or dnsq is null or queryID is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like either x or x.dnsq or x.dnsq.queryId is null for at least one item in logs.  You can check for this in your statement by doing the following:

```
    Log q = logs.Find(x => (x != null && x.dnsq != null && x.dnsq.queryID != null && x.dnsq.queryID.Contains(queryid)));
```

Comment: Or with the new `?.` operator

Comment: Well, I used the debugger to check the logs List, and I know it contains an entry where dnsq.queryID is equal to what I'm searching for.

Comment: @Mathias_ doesn't matter if the list contains it or not, as long as one of the field is null it will throw null exception

Comment: Great, that seems to have dont the trick, thanks alot!